# Zend Form is not showing on my phtml page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to build a simple test application using `Zend Framework 1.12.7`. I have the following code to create a `form` in a file in the `forms` folder called `Album.php`:

```
class Application_Form_Album extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('album');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');

        $artist = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('artist');
        $artist->setLabel('Artist')
               ->setRequired(true)
               ->addFilter('StripTags')
               ->addFilter('StringTrim')
               ->addValidator('NotEmpy');

        $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title');
        $title->setLabel('Title')
              ->setRequired(true)
              ->addFilter('StripTags')
              ->addFilter('NotEmpty');

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');

        $this->addElements(array($id,$artist,$title,$submit));
    }
}
```

I then added the following code to my `IndexController` `addAction()`:

```
public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Album();//Create the Form Object
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');//Set label of Submit button
        $this->view->form = $form;//Assign view for rendering

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){//If TRUE then form submitted
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if($form->isValid($formData)){//If VALUD then add record
                $artist = $form->getValue('artist');
                $title = $form->getValue('title');
                $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
                $albums->addAlbum($artist, $title);

                $this->_helper->redirector('index');//return to homepage
            }else{
                $form->populate($formData);//INVALID so repopulate the form
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my `view` `add.phtml` I added this code:

```
<?php 
$this->title = "Add new album";
$this->headTitle($this->title);
echo $this->form;
```

I am getting no errors and the title "Add new album" shows when I am on this URL

```
http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/index/add
```

does anyone know why my form is not displaying???

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs? Can you put the following lines in your application.ini to display them? phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors         = 1
settings.debug.enabled             = true

Comment: Add in application.ini and debug, your code seems ok: 
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
phpSettings.display_startup_errors                 = 1
phpSettings.display_errors                         = 1

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've figured it out, and it might be useful for anyone who is just starting to use `Zend` Like myself. Anyways as of `Zend Framework v1.12` the correct way to create a `form` is by using the `addElement` method for each `element` of the form. So the correct way to render my `form` included in my original post is like this:

```
public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('album');
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement('hidden', 'id', array(
            'filters'=>array('Int')
        ));

        $this->addElement('text', 'artist', array(
           'label' => 'Artist',
           'required'=> true,
           'filters'=>array('StringTrim','StripTags'),
           'validators'=>array('NotEmpty')
        ));

        $this->addElement('text', 'title', array(
           'label' => 'Title',
           'required'=> true,
           'filters'=>array('StripTags'),
           'validators'=>array('NotEmpty')
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'=>true,
            'label'=>'Create'
        ));
    }
```

Comment: This seems wierd because I also have a Zend project (working :P) and I have made my form like you did in the original post by instantiating each element in the form and adding them as an array as You did...wierd

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was the issue. `Form::addElements()` is still in v1.12.7: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/release-1.12.7/library/Zend/Form.php#L1145

Comment: I'm using latest version of Zend 1 in my project and i have forms made in both ways without a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it`s 1.12.3

Answer (score 0):

Your form creation and handling differs from mine in only two ways:

1. I typically set the form in the view at the bottom, after all the checks and processing, just before exiting the method.
2. I do not believe that it is necessary for you have the `else` clause in which you populate the form with the `$formData`. The call to `isValid($formData)` "essentially" does that.

Still hard to see why either of these would cause your form not to render, but worth a try.